# How to save the state of Fragments when using FragmentStatePageAdapter and custom classes (Serializable Relative Layout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I need to have a Relative Layout that's Serializable because I need to pass it in the Bundle of the creation of a newInstance of a Fragment (just casting it in to Serializable didn't work).

I did like this.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements Serializable {

    public SerializableRelativeLayout(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public SerializableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public SerializableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

}
```

In the layout files I use it like this:

```
<packagename.utils.SerializableRelativeLayout
```

It's working fine, but the problem is that if I go to the background, or start a new activity, when going back to the previous activity that contains a SerializableRelativeLayout, the app crashes with the messages:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: android.widget.RelativeLayout; IllegalAccessException
```

and

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = packagename.utils.SerializableRelativeLayout
```

Fragments without this, I have no problem. So I'm guessing I need to save the instance of the fragments (I know I should already be doing this). Then comes the problem, I'm using a fragmentStatePageAdapter, and I couldn't find anywhere how to save it. These are my classes.

```
public class GalleryPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Page> pageList;
    private SerializableRelativeLayout parentActivity;
    private String pathToTrack;

    public GalleryPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Page> pageList, SerializableRelativeLayout parentActivity, String pathToTrack) {
        super(fm);
        this.pageList = pageList;
        this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
        this.pathToTrack = pathToTrack;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return ContentGalleryFragment.newInstance(pageList.get(i), pageList.size(), parentActivity, pathToTrack);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pageList.size();
    }

}
```

And

```
public class ContentGalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private final static String PAGE = "page";
    private final static String PAGE_COUNT = "pageCount";
    private final static String RELATIVE_LAYOUT = "relativeLayout";
    private final static String PATH = "pathToTrack";

    private Page contentPage;
    private int pagesCount;
    private SerializableRelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private String pathToTrack;

    public ContentGalleryFragment(){

    }

    public final static ContentGalleryFragment newInstance(Page contentPage, int pagesCount, SerializableRelativeLayout relativeLayout, String pathToTrack) {
        ContentGalleryFragment fragment = new ContentGalleryFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(4);
        bundle.putSerializable(PAGE, contentPage);
        bundle.putInt(PAGE_COUNT, pagesCount);
        bundle.putSerializable(RELATIVE_LAYOUT, relativeLayout);
        bundle.putString(PATH, pathToTrack);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return  fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content_gallery, container, false);

        contentPage = (Page) getArguments().getSerializable(PAGE);
        pagesCount = getArguments().getInt(PAGE_COUNT);
        relativeLayout = (SerializableRelativeLayout) getArguments().getSerializable(RELATIVE_LAYOUT);
        pathToTrack = getArguments().getString(PATH);

        ContentDetailHelper contentHelper = new ContentDetailHelper(relativeLayout, pathToTrack);
        contentHelper.createContentDetailsPage(contentPage, pagesCount, inflater, rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_content_gallery_linearLayout_root));

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable(PAGE, contentPage);
        outState.putInt(PAGE_COUNT, pagesCount);
        outState.putSerializable(RELATIVE_LAYOUT , relativeLayout);
        outState.putString(PATH, pathToTrack);
    }

    @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //probably orientation change
            contentPage = (Page) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(PAGE);
            pagesCount = savedInstanceState.getInt(PAGE_COUNT);
            relativeLayout = (SerializableRelativeLayout) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(RELATIVE_LAYOUT);
            pathToTrack = savedInstanceState.getString(PATH);
        }
    }

}
```

I know we should Override onSaveInstanceState when we are doing a simple Activty / Fragment . But I couldn't find how to do with a ViewPager.

It's my first question here, so, sorry if it's too long or not well explained/wrong title.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't simply serialize a whole view. Let alone a ViewGroup

Comment: Huuum, I didn't knew. It's the first time I've done this.The strange thing is that it works in a lot of cases. Tricky stuff =\. Thanks for the tip. (Do you happen to know how to save instance in page views? )